# An application of Topping's diameter estimates

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

We recall Topping's diameter estimates (Theorem 1.1 [here](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maseq/topping_CMH_040407.pdf)):

> > (Topping): Let $M$ be an n-dimensional closed, connected manifold smoothly immersed in $\mathbb R^N$, where $N\ge n+1$. Then the intrinsic diameter and the mean curvature $H$ of $M$ are related by 
> >     $$
> > \operatorname{diam}(M)\le C(n)\int_M |H|^{n-1}d\mu
> > $$

Now, if we have 
$$
\max_{M} |\nabla H|\le C\epsilon^\alpha   
~~~~\text{    and }~~~~~~
\max_M |H| \ge C\epsilon^{\frac{\alpha}{2} }
$$
Then, by Topping Lemma, how to show 
$$
\min_M  |H|  \ge \frac{C}{2}\epsilon^{\frac{\alpha}{2} }
$$
As my understand, we should have 
$$
\min_M |H|\ge C\epsilon^\frac{\alpha}{2} -diam(M)C\epsilon^\alpha
$$
So it means
$$
\int_M |H|^{n-1} \thicksim \epsilon^{-\frac{\alpha}{2}}
$$
Obviously, it is not right. Where is my mistake ?

Last, this question is from the Lemma 3.4 of [**Blow-up of the mean curvature at the first singular time of the mean curvature flow**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00526-016-1003-x).
I am not sure a lot whether I understand the author, or I miss something, so ,I add the picture in below.

> [image]

Comment: If you are interested, we can talk about this paper (for example, in the [geometry and topology chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20807/geometry-topology)) as I am recently reading this paper.

Comment: @JohnMa  Thanks very much, I will talk about it in geometry and topology chat room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Topping's lemma together with the bound $|H| \le 4n\Lambda_0^2$ and $|M_t|\le |M_0|$ give

$$\text{diam} M_t \le C(n, \lambda_0, |M_0|). $$

Then

$$\min H \ge \eta - C\epsilon^\alpha = \eta - C \epsilon^{\alpha/2}\epsilon^{\alpha/2} = \eta - C\eta \epsilon^{\alpha/2}$$

(the constant might be changing, but it depends only on $n$, $\Lambda_0$ and $|M_0|$). Now choose $\epsilon$ small depending only on $C,\alpha$ so that $C\epsilon^{\alpha/2} <1/2$. Then you have

$$\min H \ge \eta - \frac 12 \eta = \frac 12 \eta$$

as claimed.